# Clear the heading in Oracle spool

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, spool

I have spooled a file before running the below command and got the output like this,

I have set heading off, feedback off

```
SET HEADING OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SPOOL D:\TEST.TXT
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;
SPOOL OFF
```

**OUTPUT in TEST.TXT:**

```
SQL> SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;

20-JAN-09

SQL> SPOOL OFF
```

How can i remove the two SQL> lines. I want only the output.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The command you need is:

```
SET ECHO OFF
```

However, it only works for code run from scripts, not command entered interactively.  You would create a script file like this (e.g. called **test.sql**):

```
SET HEADING OFF FEEDBACK OFF ECHO OFF PAGESIZE 0
SPOOL D:\TEST.TXT 
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL; 
SPOOL OFF
```

Then in SQL Plus run it like this:

```
SQL> @test
```

I added PAGESIZE 0 to the SET command to remove the blank line you otherwise get before the date in the output file.

Comment: Thanks Tony your idea works. And benjamin thanks for your scripts.

Cheers,
Seenu.

Comment: Feel free to upvote any answers you liked and accept the one that best resolved your issue!

Answer (score 4):

use this:

```
#!/bin/ksh
CONNECT_STRING=dbapp/dbapp@inst
SQLPLUS_SETTINGS="SET PAGESIZE 1000 LINESIZE 500 ECHO OFF TRIMS ON TAB OFF FEEDBACK OFF HEADING OFF"
SQL_RESULT=`sqlplus -s ${CONNECT_STRING} << EOF
${SQLPLUS_SETTINGS}
select sysdate from dual;
exit;
EOF`

echo $SQL_RESULT >output_file
```

Comment: No it shows the same. Please find the output

SQL> SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;

20-JAN-10
SQL> SPOOL OFF

Comment: check now with the modified answer

Comment: + This solution doesn't wrap or truncate the lines. That's what I was looking for.